# 12 colunas de meses => 1 coluna de valores + 1 coluna de mês

Tags: sql

Tenho uma tabela com ligação SQL(PERVASIVE) com uma coluna por cada mês, ou seja, 12.
De forma a melhor trabalharos os dados, necessito de transformar as 12 colunas em somente 2... uma 1ª com os valores que estavam nas 12 colunas e uma 2ª coluna com o respetivo mês, ou seja, o que era antes do título das colunas.

Um exemplo da tabela atual:

```
Al_Cta     | MoedCod | TpVal   | FlagDC  | Month01 | Month02 | Month03
AAAAA      |     100 |      20 |        5|      15 |      18 |      16
BBBBB      |     200 |      40 |       10|      20 |      21 |      26
CCCCC      |     300 |      60 |       15|      40 |      48 |      41
```

E quero:

```
Al_Cta     |  MoedCod|TpVal | FlagDC  | Value   | Month
AAAAA      |     100 |    20|       5 |      15 |     01
AAAAA      |     100 |    20|       5 |      18 |     02
AAAAA      |     100 |    20|       5 |      16 |     03
BBBBB      |     200 |    40|      10 |      20 |     01
BBBBB      |     200 |    40|      10 |      21 |     02
BBBBB      |     200 |    40|      10 |      26 |     03
CCCCC      |     300 |    60|      15 |      40 |     01
CCCCC      |     300 |    60|      15 |      48 |     02
CCCCC      |     300 |    60|      15 |      41 |     03
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou usar UNPIVOT?

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_teste (Al_Cta varchar(10), MoedCod int, TpVal int, FlagDC int, Month01 int, Month02 int, Month03 int);

INSERT INTO tbl_teste VALUES ('AAAAA', 100, 20, 5, 15, 18, 16);
INSERT INTO tbl_teste VALUES ('BBBBB', 200, 40, 10, 20, 21, 26);
INSERT INTO tbl_teste VALUES ('CCCCC', 300, 60, 15, 40, 48, 41);


SELECT Al_Cta, MoedCod, TpVal, FlagDC, mes, valor
FROM 
    (SELECT Al_Cta, MoedCod, TpVal, FlagDC, Month01, Month02, Month03 FROM tbl_teste) p
UNPIVOT
    (valor FOR Mes IN
        (Month01, Month02, Month03)
    )AS UNPIVOT_tbl_teste
```

Comment: Obrigado.
Tem usar o UNPIVOT, mas não estou a conseguir colocar corretamente o comando no SQL.
Neste comando, está-se a colocar os valores manualmente? (das 2ª à 4ª linha)
É que esta base de dados é só um exemplo, a real tem milhares de linhas.

Comment: Foi só para criar uma tabela de testes com alguns valores, é só adaptar para sua tabela original. Para testar, coloque numa temporária uns 50 registros.

Comment: Copiei e colei no Texto do Comando, mas recebi a mensagem de que não é suportado. :(

Comment: No create, troca o int por integer, veja se funciona. Não sei exatamente como está rodando o comando.

Comment: Mesmo problema, dá não suportado. :(

Comment: Tenta rodar direto na sua tabela, não precisa criar uma pra testar, apenas formate para a sua.