# Como posso aplicar Unpivot em uma select simples, quero deixar na vertical uma consulta

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Conforme o código abaixo:

`SELECT 
1 DADO1
,2 DADO2
FROM   DUAL`

Gostaria de deixar o resultado da pesquisa na vertical, sou iniciante em Oracle, vi que da pra fazer com o unpivot mas não encontrei um exemplo simples demonstrando a inversão de colunas na vertical e seus resultados ao lado de cada campo.

Comment: Que eu saiba, no Oracle é igual no SQL. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189841/12-colunas-de-meses-1-coluna-de-valores-1-coluna-de-m%C3%AAs/189863#189863

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme consulta utilizada, segue abaixo como ficaria. Para adequar ao seu cenário, recomendo consultar a [Documentação - Pivot and Unpivot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) <sup>EN</sup>.

```
SELECT valor
  FROM ((SELECT '1' dado1
               ,'2' dado2
               ,'3' dado3
               ,'4' dado4
               ,'5' dado5
           FROM dual)
        unpivot(valor FOR tipo_de_valor IN (dado1
                                 ,dado2
                                 ,dado3
                                 ,dado4
                                 ,dado5)))
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo exemplo David, vou implementar aqui na consulta.